# protobuf.serializer.serialize equivalnce in C++

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am writing adapter class (library function) which will take different kind of PB messages as the input in the form of std::Map and  serialize this map write in to the file then vice versa.

Example:

```
message user_defined_type 
{
    optional int Val1 = 1;
    optional string Val2 = 2;
}

message Store
{
    optional int Key = 1;
    optional user_defined_type Value = 2;
}
```

The client will create std::Map and stores the above message (i.e., std::map  XYZ). The library takes the std::Map as input and does serializing the message and store it in to the file. But the library don't have/know the Proto message definitions.

To achieve the above came up with an approach, the library will have intermediate proto message which has both the fields are byte type

```
message MAP
{
  optional byte KeyField = 1;
  optional byte ValueField = 2;
}
```

Such that the KeyField takes has value of Store::Key and ValueField has the value of Store::user_defined_type so the serialization and de-serialization will be generic for all type of messages.

In C# using the **protobuf.serializer.serialize** I can serialize/de-serialize to the designated type but in C++ don't know how to make it, any help/pointer much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the challenge is that your library needs to know how to parse `ValueField` (and perhaps `KeyField`) but the library itself does not know their types; only the caller of the library does.

The way to solve this is to have the caller pass in a "prototype" instance of their message type, from which you can spawn additional instances:

```
map<string, Message*> parse(string data, const Message& prototype) {
  map<string, Message*> result;
  MapProto proto;
  proto.ParseFromString(data);
  for (int i = 0; i < proto.entry_size(); i++) {
    Message* value = prototype->New();
    value->ParseFromString(proto.entry(i).value());
    result[proto.entry(i).key()] = value;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The caller would call this function like:

```
map<string, Message*> items = parse(data, MyValueType::default_instance());
```

Then, each message in the returned map will be an instance of `MyValueType` (the caller can use `static_cast` to cast the pointer to that type). The trick is that we had the caller pass in the default instance of their type, and we called its `New()` method to construct additional instances of the same type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is, the client creates std::map out of the .proto file (i.e., for the above example std::map<int32, user_defined_type> ClientMap) and acts on this map. The client has to go via library to save it in to the file. The library does the serialization and writing to file. There can be many clients each has its own proto definitions. Since the library code  don't have definition of the client proto messages I don't know how to serialize and also the library code has to do vice versa (i.e., read the file contents should build a map and return to the client).

Comment: The MapProto is not defined in protobuf 2.5.0 version. The above code describes the de-serialization part only can you explain how to serialize the message.

Comment: My `MapProto` is what you call `MAP` -- I changed the name to be more stylistically correct. Serialization is much easier -- you just take the map<string, Message*> and call `msg->SerializeToString(entry->mutable_value())` on each message to serialize it into place.